# Return numeric value and addClass

Tags: jquery

I need to find the numeric value inside a div and add a class accordingly. How do I find the numeric value? This seems to only return class of 'medium' so far.

```
<h4 class="days">Over <span class="filterUrgency">71</span> Days</h4>

$('.days').addClass(function() {
    if ($('.filterUrgency').val() >100) {
        return 'urgent';
    } else {
        return 'medium';
    }
});
```

or

```
$('.days').addClass(function() {
var number = parseInt($('.filterUrgency').text());
    if (number >100) {
        return 'urgent';
    } else {
        return 'medium';
    }
});
```

Comment: See me response it's tested and works ! hope this help you !

Comment: My The Second solution seems to be better in case you have many divs with the same class "days" !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as following :

```
$('.days').addClass(function() {
    if (Number($(".filterUrgency").html()) >100) {
        return 'urgent';
    } else {
        return 'medium';
    }
});
```

This solution is better :

```
$.each($('.days'),function()
{
if (Number($(this).find(".filterUrgency").html()) >100) {
        $(this).addClass('urgent');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('medium');
    }
});
```

Comment: No need for an explicit cast to Number.

Comment: Any arguments in favor of the second approach?

Comment: see additional possibility using parseInt?

Comment: addClass apply class to all div with class "days" means that the last div will apply the change for all the others !

Comment: @simple no need to use cast as Jan said ! the second solution is working like charm even without cast I just test it !